# Reading image from google storage bucket and transforming using sharp fails

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, sharp

I am trying to read an image from google cloud storage bucket in my firebase function and extracting a part of it using sharp library as below

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('XXX.appspot.com')
const filePath = '1558520481853'

   const pipeline = sharp().extract({ left: 0, top: 0, width: 30, height: 30 }).toBuffer().then( 
       (data:any) => 
                    console.log("data is::::" + data)
   );

    bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline);
```

this fails with error

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/srv/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:590:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/index.js:49:46)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/lib/index.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/srv/lib/index.js:3:12)
    at exports.extract_text_from_bounding_box.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/lib/index.js:39:82)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

I was following sample https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/image-sharp/functions/index.js which is writing back to storage bucket which i dont need and just need a base64 of extracted image

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the "pipe" method.

On this line:

```
 bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline);
```

Try this:

```
 bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline());
```